# SSMS cannot determine if remote computer is connected to domain

Tags: ssms, azure, active-directory, domain

I've recently set up a new server with an SQL instance running on it (2017), I am able to connect to the server remotely using SSMS, but when I try to add a new login, I receive the attached error. Both machines are on the same domain.

[image: error received]

I have already done some prior research and opened up ports 5002, 5001, 135 and 88 in the below configuration.

[image: opened ports]

I have already confirmed that it is an issue with the firewall, as turning off the domain firewall allows access.

Am I missing something?

In case it's relevant, the server is hosted on Azure

Comment: Did you try using Azure Data Studio?

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue with the picker for selecting accounts when it cannot connect to the SMB port (or if NetBIOS isn't enabled, but you state that it works if you disable the firewall).

You can either try to open port 445 on the firewall or create the login using T-SQL.

There used to be a [Microsoft KB Article](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/816818) for older versions of Windows but I believe this still applies.